# Unable to find the cause of String Index Out of Bound Exception in my MapReduce code

Tags: java, mapreduce

I am trying out a MapReduce code written in Java. I need to get the number of employees who were promoted in each department but still left the organization. I am trying to pass concatenated value of department and promotion as the key and resignation as the value.

**Sample Data**

left    promotion_last_5years   deptartment

1,      0,      sales

1,  1,      sales

1,  1,  hr

1,  0,  sales

**Mapper Code:**

```
public void map(LongWritable key, Text text, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException
 {
     String row = text.toString();
        String [] values = row.trim().split(",");
        int left = 0;
        int promotion = 0;
        String dept = "";
        String DeptPromoted = "";
        try
        {
            if(values.length == 10 && !header.equals(row))
            {
                left = Integer.parseInt(values[6]);
                promotion = Integer.parseInt(values[7]);
                dept = values[8];
                DeptPromoted = dept+"-"+values[7];  //  sales-0                 
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        context.write(new Text(DeptPromoted), new IntWritable(left)); //sales-0 1
    }
```

Below is my reducer code where I am using substring to seperate values of department and promotion and then use these values to calculate the number of employees promoted but resigned.

**Reducer Code:**

```
public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context throws IOException, InterruptedException
{
    //sales-0   1
    int count = 0;
    String str = "";
    str = key.toString();   //sales-0
    int len = str.length(); //7
    char L = str.charAt(len - 1);
    if (L == '1')
    {
        for (IntWritable val: values)
        {
            if(val.get() == 1)
            {
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
    context.write(key, new IntWritable(count));
}
```

I believe the StringIndexOutofBoundException is from the reducer where I am trying to get the character value at the end of the string. Can someone help to resolve the error below?

```
Error: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:658)
at com.df.hra_promleft.PromLeftReducer.reduce(PromLeftReducer.java:18)
at com.df.hra_promleft.PromLeftReducer.reduce(PromLeftReducer.java:1)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.run(Reducer.java:171)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runNewReducer(ReduceTask.java:627)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:389)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:168)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1642)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:163)
```

Comment: Can you please provide the error log?

Comment: I have added the error now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String str = "";
str = key.toString();   //sales-0    
int len = str.length(); //7   
char L = str.charAt(len - 1);
```

If **key** is an empty text then **len = 0** so **str.charAt(0-1)** is **str.charAt(-1)** it causes StringIndexOutOfBoundsException. So please check if the **Text key** is empty or not.

Comment: Thanks a lot! After just adding an if condition to check if the key is not empty, it worked!

Answer (score 0):

The IndexOutOfBoundException is probably because of the code:-

```
char L = str.charAt(len - 1);
```

Here is the reason:-

Your data includes:- 1 0 sales
and your code is splitting the data on the basis of "," (comma):-

```
String row = text.toString();
String [] values = row.trim().split(",");
```

Considering you are using normal TextInputFormat. your values will always have only one record.

In that scenario, the key to reducer will always be blank i.e. ""

so calling

```
int len = str.length(); //7
char L = str.charAt(len - 1);
```

should throw a StringIndexOutOfBoundsException.

a sample code:-

```
String s = ""
int length = s.length()
Character c = s.charAt(length - 1)
```

My suggestion is to make appropriate changes in your code and add necessary checks.

Comment: I missed to add comma to the sample data here. My data is in a CSV file. Will it still have the issue that you had pointed out? I am not clear why the key would be blank.

Comment: It depends on the data, you can do a dry run with data to understand the issue. In the code, you are only populating the key If you have 10 elements in the array.  That means you should have at least 9 commas in your data. If you are uncertain of this then you should do a check before doing string.charAt()